# Why does Laravel9/Vite application not find the assets files after build

Tags: assets, vite, laravel-9

Having built the assets,

```
build
vite build

vite v3.0.3 building for production...
✓ 64 modules transformed.
public/build/manifest.json             0.28 KiB
public/build/assets/app.45719a2b.css   189.82 KiB / gzip: 26.83 KiB
public/build/assets/app.bbc97e91.js    117.98 KiB / gzip: 37.68 KiB
```

in a newly created Laravel 9 project I am getting the console error messages

```
GET http://localhost:8001/public/build/assets/app.45719a2b.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:8001/public/build/assets/app.bbc97e91.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Both are reported as being in the layout blade at a line containing

```
@vite('resources/js/app.js')
```

I have followed all the instructions, for getting this far that I could find, but to no avail, the same error occurs.
I have reworked this project three times using the directions and it all comes to this error.

Comment: I was having this issue when deploying to a server, managed to fix it by deleting everything on the server but the .env file and re-uploading

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `APP_URL` environment variable, for correct working `npm run build` command.
If your project works with local server tool (i.e. Valet, Homestead, Laragon, Wamp and etc), you need to add `server` section in your `vite.config.js` like this, for correct working `npm run dev` command:

```
import {defineConfig} from 'vite';
import laravel        from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/js/app.js',
                'resources/sass/app.scss'
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    server: {
        https: false,
        host: 'yoursite.loc',
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the vite "hot" file in /public folder.
If that file is there, then it will run in development/staging mode and use the dev css/js files.

Just in case, I have added this to my production & stage server update script:
rm ./public/hot

And added this to my .gitignore file: /public/hot

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

Remove or comment these values from your .env file

```
# ASSET_URL="${APP_URL}"
# VITE_ASSET_URL="${APP_URL}"
```

and remove `public/hot` file if its exist

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve this by using the `php artisan serve` command, which basically means serving my website from laravel's built-in server. Initially I had used `php -S 0.0.0.0:$PORT public/index.php` which caused this issue.

Comment: Building is for production. php -S is for Local development.